# when using different file descripter, why is the result different? (system programming)

Tags: c, systems-programming, dup2

I am studying about file descripter and realized that if I use `dup2()` function,
the result will be different.

The first snippet ...

```
int main(void){
    char buf1[BUFSIZ] = "I am low\n";

    printf("i am high\n");
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));

    return 0;
}
```

... produces the following result:

```
i am high
i am low 
i am low
i am low
```

But the second snippet ...

```
int main(void){
    int fd = open("dupout",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0655);
    char buf1[BUFSIZ] = "I am low\n";
    dup2(fd, 1);

    printf("i am high\n");
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

... produces the following content in `dupout`:

```
i am low 
i am low
i am low
i am high
```

Why do the results differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

explain:

IO buffer have three types `full buffer`, `line buffer` and `no buffer`.

First example:

Default, `stdout` is `line buffer`, means when the buffer is fulled or when meet `\n`, buffer will flush.

```
int main(void){
    char buf1[BUFSIZ] = "I am low\n";
    printf("i am high\n");
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
i am high
I am low
I am low
I am low
```

But when we change it to :

```
int main(void){
    char buf1[BUFSIZ] = "I am low\n";
    printf("i am high");   // no '\n'
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
I am low
I am low
I am low
i am high
```

continue : change to :

```
int main(void){
    char buf1[BUFSIZ] = "I am low\n";
    printf("i am high"); // no '\n'
    fflush(stdout);// flush
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
i am highI am low
I am low
I am low
```

Second example:

Default, `file IO` is `full buffer`, means when the buffer is fulled, buffer will flush.

```
int main(void){
    int fd = open("dupout",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0655);
    char buf1[BUFSIZ] = "I am low\n";
    dup2(fd, 1);

    printf("i am high\n");
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
I am low
I am low
I am low
i am high
```

But when we change it to :

```
int main(void){
    int fd = open("dupout",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0655);
    char buf1[BUFSIZ] = "I am low\n";
    dup2(fd, 1);

    printf("i am high\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
i am high
I am low
I am low
I am low
```

---

```
          old
```

Because of IO buffer. If you add `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` before `printf`, result is right. The line means set no IO buffer.

The following is all `code`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
    int fd = open("dupout",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0655);
    char buf1[BUFSIZ] = "I am low\n";
    dup2(fd, 1);

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf("i am high\n");
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does write() function also have IO buffer?  and I am wondering when the IO buffer will be empty in printf() function.

Comment: @whitehat IO buffer just for Standard IO, like `printf`, `fputs`  and so on. `write`, `read` is system call.

Comment: @whitehat I have added a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you. it was really helpful to me